# Download entity classes of jbpm 6.0.1

Tags: jbpm

I created a jbpm project and it works well.
The entity classes listed on the file `persistence.xml` are the following:

```
<class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
<class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo</class>
<class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
<class>org.jbpm.persistence.correlation.CorrelationKeyInfo</class>
<class>org.jbpm.persistence.correlation.CorrelationPropertyInfo</class>

<class>org.jbpm.process.audit.ProcessInstanceLog</class>
<class>org.jbpm.process.audit.NodeInstanceLog</class>
<class>org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog</class>

<!-- manager -->
<class>org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.jpa.ContextMappingInfo</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.AttachmentImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.ContentImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.BooleanExpressionImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.CommentImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.DeadlineImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.DelegationImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EscalationImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.GroupImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.I18NTextImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.NotificationImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EmailNotificationImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EmailNotificationHeaderImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.PeopleAssignmentsImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.ReassignmentImpl</class>

<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskDataImpl</class>
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.UserImpl</class>

<!--BAM for task service -->
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.BAMTaskSummaryImpl</class>

<!-- Event Classes -->
<class>org.jbpm.services.task.audit.TaskEventImpl</class>
```

I need to put those classes on a package called for example `com.acme.rewards.entities` like this [image].

Could you please tell me where can I find the **java code** of all those entities?.

Answer (score 0):

You can find them in [Drools](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/tree/6.0.x) and [jBPM](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/tree/6.0.x) repositories on branch **6.0.x**. But why do you need to put them in different package?

And why do you use such old version? I would recommend you to use **6.4.0.Final**.

Comment: Hello @CacheStaheli, I would like to create queries for example "SELECT t FROM TaskImpl t" --> so TaskImpl must be an entity class. I'm asking if there's a possibility to create a query with entity TaskImpl knowing that we have "org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskImpl" on persistence.xml

Comment: You do not have to create such queries yourself. There is a new [Query Service](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e2607) in jBPM 6.4. You can find really nice overview in [this blog post](http://mswiderski.blogspot.cz/2016/01/advanced-queries-in-jbpm-64.html). Anyway, how do you use jBPM? Do you have the engine embedded in your application or do you use KIE Workbench (jBPM Console) or KIE Server?

Comment: Hi @CacheStaheli, Thanks for your help. I used jBPM on 2 cases:the first is like an embedded engine in my application and the second I worked with KIE-WB and I tried to connect KIE-WB with a dynamic project using REST api. those 2 projects are created with jBPM 6.0.1 while I built them since January 2014. Now I'm trying to migrate to jBPM 6.4.0 that you recommend.